# Fix useEffect infinity loop - useState array as dependency

Tags: reactjs

If I have an array in useState, and I have a requirement to have a useEffect that runs when one prop updates. And inside the useEffect, I need to do some operation on the array items, and then update the array, I have an infinite loop!

I'm stumped! Here's the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/reactforever/w1zoqka2/11

Here's the code:

```
const HooksAreWeird = ({anArrayFromProps}) => {

  const [myArray, setMyArray] = React.useState(['a', 'b', 'c']);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    
      // do some operation with my array
      myArray.forEach(el => {
          const someCalculation = el.indexOf('a');
      });
    
     // re-assign my array
     const newArray = anArrayFromProps.map(el => {
         return el.letterFromAlphabet;
     });
     setMyArray(newArray);
  
     console.log("------useEffect")
 }, [myArray, anArrayFromProps]);

  return (
    <div>
       {myArray.map(el => (
        <span key={el}>
          {el}
        </span>
       ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop because you are updating myArray inside the useEffect. Because the useEffect runs when myArray gets updated, you now have an infinite loop

Comment: I understand that. I guess I'm looking for another pattern that wouldn't cause the infinite loop.

Comment: AMunim gave a good answer on how to solve it.

Comment: Ah yeah, I guess you're not supposed to infer state from props. That's the anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using 2 arrays? one for hooks and one for final product

```js
const HooksAreWeird = () => {

  const [myArray, setMyArray] = React.useState(['a', 'b', 'c']);
  const [fArray, setfArray] = React.useState([1, 2, 3]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    
      // do some operation with my array
      myArray.forEach(el => {
          const someCalculation = el.indexOf('a');
      });
    
     // re-assign my array
     const newArray = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
     setfArray(newArray);
  
     console.log("------useEffect")
 }, [myArray, /*aPropFromParentWhichShouldTriggerThisFunc*/]);

  return (
    <div>
       {fArray.map(el => (
        <span key={el}>
          {el}
        </span>
       ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```